# How to get the name of role from pivot table for a users in laravel?

Tags: database, laravel, query-builder

`Admin.php`    [Middlewere]

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
   if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role->name == 'admin') {
      return $next($request);
   }
   return Redirect::route('home');
}
```

> I want to check if the column **`name`** of `roles` table is equal to `admin`.

> I have tried with `Auth::user()->role->name == 'admin')`.

**Error I am getting**

> Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance.

**Reference Model**

`User.php` [Model]

```php
public function role()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

**Reference table**

`users` table

```php
         Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('photo')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->longText('cartitems')->nullable();
            $table->longText('wishlist')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('discount')->default(0);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

> This is `users` table. **Notice** there is no role directly here.

`roles` table

```php
       Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('display_name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

> This is `roles` table. And every user have a role such as `Superadmin`, `admin`, `seller` or`customer`

`role_user` table

```php
        Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

> In this pivot table make a relationship between `users` and `roles` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're trying to access a value on `collection` and your laravel relationship is [BelongsToMany](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) but rather [HasOne/BelongsTo](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one). You should rather pluck all the names and then check if it exist `in_array`

```
$roles = Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->role->pluck('name')->toArray() : [];

if (in_array('admin', $roles)) {
  return $next($request);
}
```

I would recommend changing the **role** relationship to **roles** rather because a user can have many roles in this context.

Comment: @ImrulHasan please accept it as it will help others in future. Thanks

Comment: Bro.... if I want check if role is `admin` or `seller`. What changes need to do?

Comment: @ImrulHasan `in_array('seller', $roles) || in_array('admin', $roles)`

Answer (score 2):

It's because a user can have many roles as per your schema design.

User <=> Role  : Many to Many Relation

So `Auth::user()->role` gives a collection of instances of Role Model. And you're trying to access name property on the collection which can't be done.

Change the if condition to this

```
if (Auth::check() && Auth::user->role()->where('name', 'admin')->exists()) {
```

I'd also suggest you to change the name of the relation from `role` to `roles` in your User Model. as `roles` is more informative about the type of relation user and role share.

```
public function roles(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(App\Role::class, 'role_user' 'user_id', 'role_id');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

```
 if (Auth::check() && User::where('id',Auth::user()->id)->whereHas('role',function ($query){
           $query->where('roles.name','=','admin');
       })->first()!=null ) {
      return $next($request);
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Use whereHas**

```
$role = User::where('id',Auth::user()->id)->whereHas('role',function ($query){
           $query->where('name','=','admin');
       })->first();

if (Auth::check() && isset($role) && !empty($role) ) {
      return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Try this way...!!

Comment: works, i completely forgot that there is a wherehas clasuse